# How to edit to look like code?

Tags: support, editing

How can I make it so this,

## The primary network interface

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

looks the same as it appears on the monitor, like this:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it magically edited itself but on ask-ubuntu it does not appear like that without some extra work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code formatting is done in several ways:

If it's inline code you add backticks (`) around it. `This is some inline formatting`.

For code on it's own line you indent it by four spaces:

```
This is code on it's own line.
```

Or you can use the code button on the toolbar:

[image]

Which can also be activated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

For more information see [formatting help](http://meta.askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: Make sure that you've got a blank line before the code block if you're doing it manually. The code button does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

One incredibly annoying behaviour of the editor shortcut is that it doesn't account for levels. If you try to embed code within a list, you'll need to add the indentation once more (and more times per level). So:

```
 - some text

    code
```

Shows up as:

- some text

  code

You can add it manually, but one trick is to indent the code, then in the first line of the block, add a character at the start of the line, and then indent it again:

```
- some text
code
```

Becomes:

```
- some text

    code
```

Then:

```
- some text

a    code
```

Then:

```
- some text

    a    code
```

And finally delete that extra character.

Backticks work in lists, but backtick-quoted code blocks aren't as nicely formatted as the indented version.